# Does QGIS use data source-specific operations?

Tags: qgis, postgis, spatial-join

This may be a very basic question, but I couldn't find an appropriate answer.

Does QGIS use data source specific operations where available and appropriate? For example, when using the `Join attributes by location` dialogue to join two layers within the same PostGIS database, will QGIS create an appropriate SQL query and run that query on the PostGIS server? Or will QGIS fetch all relevant features and do the join locally?

I know that I can write my own queries through plugins and/or DB manager, just interested in the default behaviour?

Comment: You can test it by turning on DB logging to see what request is sent by QGIS

Comment: I guess it would depend on how the layers and the query are handled. If you have included those layers in a project and use the QGIS tool, it would run within the QGIS core. If, on the other hand, you run it as an SQL query in, for example, a virtual layer, the query would run in the PostgreSQL server.